# Using the 'get' form to pass the value to the next view in Django

Tags: django, forms

I try to pass the value (from the completed form) form one view to the next view using the get method. My **view** looks like this.

```
def search(request): 
    if request.method == 'GET' and 'search' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:search_results'))
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'search.html', context)
```

and simple **forms.py**

```
class SearchForm
    country = models.ChoiceField(choices=COUNTRY)
    city= models.ChoiceField(choices=CITY)
```

I tried to use args (to pass city and country to `search_results` view) `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:search_results', args=[country, city]))` but my url next views looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search-results/USA/new-york/
```

but I expect something like that (after redirecting to the next view):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search-results/?country=USA&city=new-york&
```

How can I do this? For example, after choosing the location and type of work on this [page](https://www.indeed.com/), we see a similar url to example 2 not 1 (as on most websites).

### Edit

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.search, name='search'),
    path('search-results/<country>/<city>/', views.search_results, name='search_results'),
```

Comment: Can you please share your `urls.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a [**`QueryDict`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict). You can thus generate such `QueryDict` to construct the query parameters, like:

```
from django.http import QueryDict

qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
qd.update(country='USA', city='new york')

return HttpResponseRedirect(
    '{}?{}'.format(reverse('app:search_results'), qd.urlencode())
)
```

If you thus `urlencode()` the querydict, you get:

```
>>> qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
>>> qd.update(country='USA', city='new york')
>>> qd.urlencode()
'country=USA&city=new+york'
```

You will need to eliminate the parameters from your `urls.py`:

```
path('search-results/', views.search_results, name='search_results'),
```

since otherwise those parameters are missing.

Comment: "Bureaucrat Conrad, you are technically correct — the best kind of correct. I hereby promote you to grade 37."   (IOW; may I kindly suggest that the real issue here is not "how to do this", but "why would anyone do this at all when it's totally useless") ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: well this is a frequent pattern if you have multiple buttons, each with a `name` and (`value`). You can for example define a button `<button name="search" type="submit">Search all</button>` and `<button name="history" type="submit">history</button>`. Usually in software design orthogonal things are performed by different things (well I agree that imperative programming has more issues with that). But I would in that case suggest using a redirect. Note that we functionally here "pop" the `search=...` parameter from the querystring :)

Comment: I vey seldom had a case of two different submit buttons _in the same form_ (in almost 20 years...) and whenever this happened, the functionalities behind barely qualified as "orthogonal". IOW, if you have two buttons doing different things, you certainly want two different forms, each pointing to it's own url. My 2 cents...

Comment: NB: I'm not saying there _never_ can be a valid reason to have a redirection between the form submission and the result url, but that 1/ it's something quite rare in my experience and 2/ it's still not needed here (unless of course you know something about this project that isn't mentionned in the question)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: well the fact that there is likely some data introduced is because the `search` get parameter comes from somewhere :), and it can not be part of the form (given that form contains no extra fields) :). It might not be necessary by using the `formaction=` attribute, etc. But somehow that is unpopular. Nested forms are unfortunately in HTML not possible (well it makes sense, because that would introduce a lot of problems with semantics).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean in your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Not really hard if i understood clearly,
you can call a redirect to go on another another template, and reverse to have the link coming from your "urls.py" and simply call the value you want.

return redirect(reverse('urllink')+"?id="+object.idObject)

Comment: Please do *not* manually encode the querydictionary. If your value contains characters like `+`, `&`, etc., then these needs to be escaped.

Comment: Yes that's true, i just wanted to give a quick solving issue ;),

Answer (score 0):

While Willem Van Onsem's answer is technically correct, it would probably not pass a code review here.

The simple, obvious, canonical solution here to use one single view for validating the form and displaying the results, and to point the form at this view's url (that's what the HTML form's "action" attribute is for).

If you want the form to be displayed on all pages (or at least more than one) - as is often the case with search forms -, then all you need is a simple custom templatetag that creates an empty form (which points to your "search" url).